# How to check if characters forming string are different length

Tags: c++

I want to create a function that takes in a string as a parameter and checks if the number of occurrences of the individual letters are different.

`"OBDO"` should display `NO`, because `O` occurs twice, but `B` and `D` occur once.

`"AABBB"` should display `YES`, because `A` occurs twice, and `B` occurs three times.

My code seems to work, but my code auto checker wont accept it, out of 4 tests it only passes once. I believe this can be done way better and shorter.

Can anyone advise?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

struct custom_comparator {
    bool operator()(const std::pair<int, int>& a, const std::pair<int, int>& b) const
    {
        return less_comparator(std::minmax(a.first, a.second),
                               std::minmax(b.first, b.second));
    }

    std::less<std::pair<int, int>> less_comparator;
};

int main()
{
    string word;
    string notDupes = "";
    vector<int> amount;
    vector<pair<char,int>> para;
    std::set<std::pair<char, int>, custom_comparator> unique;
    vector <int> items;
    vector <char> toIterate;
    string result;

    while(cin>>word) {
    if(word.length() > 100) {
        return 0;
    }
    for( int x=0;x<word.length();x++) {
        int isUpper = isupper(word[x]);
        if(!isUpper) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    
    for(int i =0;i<word.length();i++) {
        int times = std::count(word.begin(), word.end(), word[i]);
        para.push_back({word[i], times});
    }
    

    
    for(int pl=0;pl<para.size();pl++) {
        unique.insert(para[pl]);
    }
    
       for (auto p : unique) {
        toIterate.push_back(p.first);
        items.push_back(p.second);
        }
        
        auto it = std::unique(items.begin(), items.end());
        bool wasUnique = (it == items.end());
        if(wasUnique) {
            result = "YES";
        } else {
            result = "NO";
        }
        
        cout << result << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your approach looks rather complicated. You could sort the string, then loop over it once, making sure the same characters occurs N times for each distinct character. You determine N from the first character stride in the string.

Comment: I don't understand the rules. `OBDO`: No,  O occured twice, B and D occured once, `AABBB`: Yes. A appears twice and B three times. To me this is not enough information

Comment: *My code seems to work,* -- If the code doesn't produce the correct results, it doesn't work.  If it really did "work", then the complaint is with the "judge" that's saying your results are wrong.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I think the idea is that it's "NO" if any two characters in the string occurred the same number of times, and "YES" if each occurred a different number of times than any other.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `isupper` calls and checking for length with 100?  If it's as @JerryCoffin mentioned, this should be around 10 lines, maybe less, using a `std::map<char,int>`, where the `char` is the character, and then `int` is the count.  If anything, then some logic going through the already built map and inspecting each of the counts.  Instead I see a lot of unneeded complexity.

Comment: @JerryCoffin & #PaulMcKenzie: Thanks! I'll deliver the spaceship first thing Monday morning! It'll fly, somewhere. Promise!  :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo: So you've got the spaceship operator figured out? Cool!

Comment: @JerryCoffin Weakly ... :-) (I tried defining the return type instead of making it `auto` and gave up) `operator<` (and sometimes `operator==` will have to do for now. Annoying.

Comment: Please post more input samples, and what is supposed to be the correct output.  But from the looks of it, that code should be ripped up and a much simpler approach, [like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7af4b71b80526ce) could be used.  Whether the "auto checker" likes that, I have no idea, given the ambiguity of the question, the checking for 100 length, isupper, and the whole gamut of other things your code is doing.

Comment: `std::set<std::pair<char, int>, custom_comparator>` seems suspicious, `custom_comparator` won't exact match type and do strange comparison, `{'A', 66}` is equivalent to `{'B', 65}` (assuming ascii).

Comment: @PaulMckenzie I also had to validate the input, it only allows uppercase letters and a-z alphabet. That's why I used isupper, but I didnt figure out how to only accept letters as input.

Comment: @squnk -- [See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7e427c71eba3c65).  The `std::all_of` function replaces that entire loop you wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce the whole thing (if I understood the question correctly) to just a few rather simple steps:

1. Sort the input string, so duplicate characters end up next to each other.
2. produce a list (or vector) of the occurrence counts of each distinct character.
3. test, if the list (or vector) of those occurrence counts contains duplicates.
4. If duplicates - output "NO" else output "YES".

step 1 is easily done, using `std::sort`.

step 2 is not quite as obvious- but a `std::accumulate` (similar to `reduce` and also often called `fold`) can help with that, if we maintain the current counting and listing state in the accumulator of the operation, while iterating over the sorted strings characters.

step 3, we can do by using a `std::set<size_t>`, inserting the resulting list from step 2 into it and then compare the size of the set with the size of the list.

In C++, this can look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

struct Accumulator {
  char current;
  size_t count;
  std::vector<size_t> occurrences;
  Accumulator(char c, size_t count, std::vector<size_t> occs)
    : current{c}
    , count{count}
    , occurrences{occs}
  {
  }
};

int main (int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  if (argc >= 1) {
    std::string s = argv[1];
    auto sorted_s = s;
    std::sort(sorted_s.begin(),sorted_s.end(),std::less<char>());
    Accumulator x =
      std::accumulate(sorted_s.cbegin() + 1,
          sorted_s.cend(),
          Accumulator(*sorted_s.cbegin(),1,{}),
          [](Accumulator acc, char c) {
            if (c == acc.current) {
              return Accumulator(c,
                     acc.count + 1,
                     acc.occurrences);
            } else {
              auto acc1 = Accumulator(c,1,acc.occurrences);
              acc1.occurrences.push_back(acc.count);
              return acc1;
            }
          });
    x.occurrences.push_back(x.count);
    std::set<size_t> deduped;
    for (auto& k : x.occurrences) {
      deduped.insert(k);
    }
    if (deduped.size() == x.occurrences.size()) {
      std::cout << "Yes" << std::endl;
    } else {
      std::cout << "No" << std::endl;
    }
  } else {
    std::cout << "no input." << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And it is easily ported to other languages, offering about the same facilities. Here, for example the less verbose implementation in Common Lisp:

```lisp
(defun unique-occurrence-counts-of-chars
    (s)
  (let ((sorted-s (sort (copy-seq s) #'char<)))
    (let ((x
        (reduce #'(lambda (acc c)
            (if (char= (first (first acc)) c)
                (list
                 (list c (+ (second (first acc)) 1))
                 (second acc))
                (list
                 (list c 1)
                 (cons (second (first acc))
                   (second acc)))))
            (subseq sorted-s 1)
            :initial-value (list (list (aref sorted-s 0) 1)
                     '()))))
      (let ((y (cons (second (first x)) (second x))))
    (let ((deduped-y (remove-duplicates y)))
      (if (= (length y) (length deduped-y))
          "yes"
          "no"))))))
```

and even terser in Haskell:

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set
import Data.List
unique_occurrence_counts_of_chars:: String -> String
unique_occurrence_counts_of_chars s =
  let folder ((current, count),occs) c =
        if current == c
        then
          ((c, count + 1), occs)
        else
          ((c, 1), (count : occs)) in
    let sorted_s = sort s
        x = foldl folder ((head sorted_s, 1), []) (tail sorted_s) 
        y = (snd (fst x)) : (snd x)
        yDeduped = Set.fromList y 
    in if ((length . Set.toList) yDeduped == length y)
       then "Yes"
       else "No"
```

Comment: 1./2. can be simplified with `std::/*unordered_*/map`: `std::map<char, std::size_t> freq; for (auto c : s) { ++freq[c]; } for (const auto& [c, count] : freq) { deduped.insert(count); } return deduped.size() == freq.size();`.

Comment: @BitTickler, wondering if this could be converted to javascript?

Comment: @squnk Possibly with modern javascript. Untyped as it is and some guy even demonstrated monads in javascript... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: @Jarod42 I tried to please the "loops are evil and backwardish" crowd, I guess ;)

Comment: @BitTickler -- *I tried to please the "loops are evil and backwardish" crowd* -- But then your answer becomes more complex than it should be.  Counting frequencies in C++ is readily done by using a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`.  What couldn't be more simpler than a one line loop?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie There are plenty ways to skin a cat. I chose one, which shows the analogy to how functional languages approach the problem typically.

Comment: However the question is tagged as `C++`, thus an idiomatic solution using C++ would have sufficed.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie So you say, the headers `<functional>, <algorithm> and <numeric>` are not idiomatic c++? :) Don't blame me for the C++ community trying to incorporate anything and their...cat :)

Comment: What I'm saying is that posting stuff from other languages when the question wasn't tagged as such is overkill.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the requirements seem to be easily accomplished by utilizing a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`, and then seeing if the map size is equal to the number of items in the original string.

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

std::string Solution(std::string word)
{
    // Verify the entire string is upper case  
    if ( !std::all_of(word.begin(), word.end(), 
           [](unsigned char c) 
           { return std::isupper(c);}))
        return "NOT VALID";              
                               
    // get a count of each character in the string    
    std::map<char, int> sMap;
    for (auto c : word)
       sMap[c]++;

   // Now go through the built-up map and insert the counts
   // into the set  
   std::set<int> sCount;
   for (auto& pr : sMap)
     sCount.insert(pr.second);

   // Return "YES" if the set.size() is equal to the 
   // map size
   if ( sCount.size() == sMap.size() )
       return "YES";
    return "NO";
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << Solution("OBDO") << "\n";
    std::cout << Solution("AABBB") << "\n";
    std::cout << Solution("AA1BBB") << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
NO
YES
NOT VALID
```

The `std::map` simply increments the frequency count for each character.  The `std::set` is used, since a `std::set` does not store duplicates.  All of the counts that were accumulated in the map are inserted into the `set`.

Then it's just a matter of checking of the `std::set` number of entries matches the map's number of entries.

Also note that to check if the string is all upper-case, the `std::all_of` algorithm function with the appropriate lambda is used.